# SSRS Dataset Business object cannot be created

Tags: ms-access, reporting-services, dataset

I'm attempting to create a SSRS dataset pointing to an Access Database(I know... Access, users choice).  I created the DataSource fine as below.  When I create the dataset I get the following error:

> Business Object cannot be created.

Any help would be appreciated.

```
Provider=MS Remote; Remote Server=\\MYSERVERNAME; Remote Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0; Data Source= \\MYSERVERNAME\C:\SHARE\OVERVIEWS.mdb;
```

Thank You

Steve

Answer (score 2):

If the share exists, the correct path would be along the lines of

```
Data Source= \\MYSERVERNAME\SHARE$\OVERVIEWS.mdb
```

Comment: Same result after changing the connection string.

Comment: I don't have admin rights on my p so I can't test this, but another option would be is to try setting up a DSN to the Access database and try using an ODBC connection string in SSRS to connect.